# InfluxDB DELETE FROM command really deletes data?

Tags: database, influxdb, disk, usage-statistics

I have an InfluxDB database where I usually use the DELETE FROM measurement command, but I don't delete all records from the measurement.

I can't really find any answer for the question that if the DELETE FROM command really deletes the data from database or just the data becomes unqueryable.

Can't really find the answer anywhere.